# What should I do when the if statement in a for loop is false and I don't wanna take any operation for the false and then directly test next value?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I wanna find multiples of 2 between 0 and 100 and save these multiples in a vector.
This is my code:

```
i <- c(0:100)
a <- c()
for (value in i) {
  if (i %% 2 == 0) {
    a[i+1] <- i
  }
}
#> Warning in if (i%%2 == 0) {: the condition has length > 1 and only the first
#> element will be used

#> Warning in if (i%%2 == 0) {: the condition has length > 1 and only the first
#> element will be used

#> Warning in if (i%%2 == 0) {: the condition has length > 1 and only the first
#> element will be used
...
print(a)
#>   [1]   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17
#>  [19]  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35
#>  [37]  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53
#>  [55]  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71
#>  [73]  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89
#>  [91]  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
Created on 2020-06-12 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```

The result that I expected should be "0,2,4,6,8,10,12...".

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the way the 'a' is initialized (i.e. as `NULL` vector), we can concatenate the 'value' `if` the condition is satisified

```
a <- c()
for(value in i) if(value %%2 == 0) a <- c(a, value)

a
#[1]   0   2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18  20  22  24  26  28  30  32  34  36  38  40  42  44  46  48  50  52  54  56  58  60  62  64  66
#[35]  68  70  72  74  76  78  80  82  84  86  88  90  92  94  96  98 100
```

---

In the OP's code, the condition inside `if` is done withe the whole vector `i` instead of the 'value' resulting in the warning message because `if/else` expects a single element of TRUE/FALSE

---

This can be done without a loop in `R` as these are vectorized operations

```
i[!i %% 2]
```

Comment: I also have a question here. If I replace "i" with "value" in my OP's code (I mean correct it) and the result includes "NULL", but why when I use a <- c(a, value)" there will no NULL?

Comment: @ChrisMa  It is because `NULL` will be dropped in a `vector`.  You can try `c(1, 2, NULL, 3)`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking for every value of `i` why not generate a sequence with a step of 2.

```
i <- 0:100
seq(min(i), max(i), 2)

# [1]   0   2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18  20  22  24  26  28  30  32  34
#[19]  36  38  40  42  44  46  48  50  52  54  56  58  60  62  64  66  68  70
#[37]  72  74  76  78  80  82  84  86  88  90  92  94  96  98 100
```

Comment: Good idea! I'm not so good at finding out R function! Thank you!